# python list from for loop into one list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Python list in for loop, how do I have all in one list

```
import os
dir="/tmp/logvol/logs/fil/sap/archive/"
n=os.listdir(dir)
#print n

for x in n:
 #print x
 l = [];
 l.append(os.path.join(dir,x))
 print l
```

output:

```
['/tmp/logvol/logs/fil/sap/archive/m.log']
['/tmp/logvol/logs/fil/sap/archive/k.log']
['/tmp/logvol/logs/fil/sap/archive/j.log']
['/tmp/logvol/logs/fil/sap/archive/p.log']
```

Instead of multiple lists, I need all in one list.

```
['/tmp/logvol/logs/fil/sap/archive/m.log', '/tmp/logvol/logs/fil/sap/archive/k.log', '/tmp/logvol/logs/fil/sap/archive/j.log', '/tmp/logvol/logs/fil/sap/archive/p.log']
```

Comment: you are close: create `l` outside of the for loop (and remove the useless ending semi colon)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another way of doing it is with list comprehension.

```
l = [os.path.join(dir,x) for x in n]
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to move your declaration of the list `l` outside the loop:

```
l = []
for x in n:
 #print x
 l.append(os.path.join(dir,x))
```

Also, you don't need semicolons in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You recreate `l` list every iteration of `for` loop

```
for x in n:
    #print x
    l = []; # here You recreate list every iteration
    l.append(os.path.join(dir,x))
    print l
```

to avoid this instantiate list before `for` loop

```
l = []; # here You recreate list every iteration
for x in n:
    l.append(os.path.join(dir,x))
print l
```

and pick other name for variable, not `l` because  http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid